# Adding spring security to my current springmvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Sorry I'm rather new to Spring Security.  I've got the following applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.assessme.com" />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

</beans>
```

I'm following the tutorial on...

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html

my question is, should I add to my existing applicationContext.xml or make a seperate XML file?

My web.xml is as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm a little bit confused as in the tutorial, it specifies the context-param of the xml but I already have one declared, can I have more that one context-param?  If someone could give me an idea of the best way to use springmvc and spring security together that would be great as at the moment I'm finding it hard to "merge" the xml files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have your security configuration in a separate file or combine with your existing application Context. If you want to use existing application context. You keep the default namespace as beans like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

      <security:http auto-config="true">
         <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
      </security:http>
   ...
</beans>
```

and you have to prefix all security elements with security.

But if you define in separate files. The advantage is you can have security as the default namespace and omit the security prefix like this:

```
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

      <http auto-config='true'>
           <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
      </http>
      ...
</beans:beans>
```

The common way is to define file names like this:

```
 1)applicationContext.xml
 2)applicationContext-security.xml
```

and in your web.xml like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or as a comma or space separated list also like below:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[Documentation: ContextLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html)

[Documentation: namespace config](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-config)

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial that you're following, it also uses:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
       classpath:applicationContext-business.xml
       /WEB-INF/security-app-context.xml
   </param-value>
</context-param>
```

in which `applicationContext-business.xml` is like your `root-context.xml`. So, you need to add the path to your Spring security configuration file. And, remember to also include the security filter mentioned in your `web.xml`.

Comment: Ah, so are you saying I should have two contextConfigLocation params in my web.xml?  That's sort of where I'm confused.

Comment: As stated [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextLoader.html), you can have one `contextConfigLocation` but the `param-value` can have multiple context locations separated by spaces or commas.